# Get all sub elements of multiple tags in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I get all the sub elements of multiple elements with the same class.

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3 class="searchresult">
  <a href='/lorem1'>Text1</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="searchresult">
  <a href='/lorem2'>Text2</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="searchresult">
  <a href='/lorem3'>Text3</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="searchresult">
  <a href='/lorem4'>Text4</a>
</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to  get all the text of the a tags in the h3 **'s** with the class `searchresult` in a list say  `l=['Text1','Text2','Text3']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='searchresult']/a")
l = [i.text for i in x]
```

Edit: Wrong code, '`WebDriver`' has no attribute '`find_all_elements_by_xpath`', it should be `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`